# How to get more than one value at a time from a dictionary?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a subset of values from a Python dictionary but I am wondering if there is a quick approach.
Imagine that I have this:

```
my_dict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
```

and I want to get the values for both the `a` and `b` simultaneously as a list. I have tried the following methods and every one of them has raised an error.

```
my_dict['a', 'b']  # KeyError
my_dict[['a', 'b']]  # TypeError (unhashable type: 'list')
my_dict[('a','b')]  # KeyError
```

I have also tried the `.get` method, but it didn't work either.
Now, I am aware that I can generate a list comprehension that gives me the answer:

```
subset = [my_dict[key] for key in ["a","b"]]
```

but I was wondering if there is an easier / shorter way of doing it. Passing a list of keys as an index to a dictionary and getting the corresponding list of values with `dictionary[subset_of_keys] --> [subset_of_values]` would make sense.

Comment: would something like `list(my_dict.values())[:2]` work?

Comment: if you want to avoid a list comprehension, you could also try `[my_dict['a']] + [my_dict['b']]`, though it's not much better.